# Material Button with icon on the right

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

The [new material button](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/) from Google is really nice.
According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#setIcon(Drawable)), we can set an icon who's shown by default on the left. Does anyone knows how to set it on the right? I can't find anything about this.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible. Look at the source, line 669, it is always added to Start (left)
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton.java#L669

Comment: Hum interesting, I thought it was possible since the doc says "by default". It's pretty bad they don't let the choice in xml. 
But thanks to you, I found a workaround . I recall this method in my activity and set the icon on the right :
`TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(button, null, null, button.icon, null)`

Comment: @BenjaminLedet I am trying to set compunddrawble on the button to achieve same thing and I can't seem to fix it. Can you post code or guide me how you made the icon on the right

Comment: @Snake I just made an extension :

`fun MaterialButton.setRightIcon() {
        TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(this, null, null, this.icon, null)
}`

And I call it like `button.setRightIcon()` after view initialization

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57237630/7254873

Answer (score 29):

Just use the **[`app:iconGravity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton.html#attr_MaterialButton_iconGravity)** attribute or the method [`setIconGravity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton.html#setIconGravity(int)) in the `MaterialButton`.
In your case use **`app:iconGravity="textEnd"`** or **`app:iconGravity="end"`**.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/material_button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:icon="@drawable/outline_cached_black_18dp"
        app:iconGravity="textEnd"
        android:padding="32dp"
        android:text="@string/refresh"
        />
```

[image]

Also according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton.html):

> If a start-aligned icon is added to this button, please use a style like one of the ".Icon" styles specified in the default MaterialButton styles. The ".Icon" styles adjust padding slightly to achieve a better visual balance. This style should only be used with a start-aligned icon button. If your icon is end-aligned, you cannot use a ".Icon" style and must instead manually adjust your padding such that the visual adjustment is mirrored.

**Note:** it requires the version **1.1.0** of the materialComponents library.

---

With **Compose** you can use:

```
Button(
    onClick = { /* */ },
    modifier = modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)
) { // RowScope
    Text(
        text = text,
        maxLines = 1,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(
            id = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info
        ),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: how do i set icon on top of text?

Comment: @tejaspatel You can use app:iconGravity="top"

Answer (score 24):

I googled today the same problem and found this: `android:layoutDirection="rtl"`. It works in my test project.

Comment: Wow, that just awesome, thanks! Haven't seen such a sophisticated hack for a long time.

Answer (score 8):

There's a new gravity value for **end** in the release [1.1.0-alpha06](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0-alpha06)

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1

Use this extension method (kotlin) for each button:

```
fun MaterialButton.setRightIcon() { 
    TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(this, null, null, this.icon, null) 
}
```

## Solution 2 (better way)

Extend `MaterialButton` class to use everywhere:

```
class RtlMaterialButton(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : MaterialButton(context, attrs) {

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        updateIcon()
    }
    private fun updateIcon() {
        TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(this, null, null, icon, null)
    }

}
```

## Solution 3 (work in `minSDK>=17`)

If you want to use `textStart` gravity for icon you can use `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` for each button.

set `android:supportsRtl="true"` in your app `AndroidManifest.xml` in your `<Application>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still relevant but I found this in the [source code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/af16b051afd27c748f912091935e250188e8aa41/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton.java#L165) of `MaterialButton.java` Line 165.

```
  /**
   * Gravity used to position the icon at the start of the view.
   *
   * @see #setIconGravity(int)
   * @see #getIconGravity()
   */
  public static final int ICON_GRAVITY_START = 0x1;

  /**
   * Gravity used to position the icon in the center of the view at the start of the text
   *
   * @see #setIconGravity(int)
   * @see #getIconGravity()
   */
  public static final int ICON_GRAVITY_TEXT_START = 0x2;

  /**
   * Gravity used to position the icon at the end of the view.
   *
   * @see #setIconGravity(int)
   * @see #getIconGravity()
   */
  public static final int ICON_GRAVITY_END = 0x3;

  /**
   * Gravity used to position the icon in the center of the view at the end of the text
   *
   * @see #setIconGravity(int)
   * @see #getIconGravity()
   */
  public static final int ICON_GRAVITY_TEXT_END = 0x4;

  /**
   * Gravity used to position the icon at the top of the view.
   *
   * @see #setIconGravity(int)
   * @see #getIconGravity()
   */
  public static final int ICON_GRAVITY_TOP = 0x10;

  /**
   * Gravity used to position the icon in the center of the view at the top of the text
   *
   * @see #setIconGravity(int)
   * @see #getIconGravity()
   */
  public static final int ICON_GRAVITY_TEXT_TOP = 0x20;

  /** Positions the icon can be set to. */
  @IntDef({
      ICON_GRAVITY_START,
      ICON_GRAVITY_TEXT_START,
      ICON_GRAVITY_END,
      ICON_GRAVITY_TEXT_END,
      ICON_GRAVITY_TOP,
      ICON_GRAVITY_TEXT_TOP
  })
```