# How to get material icon button in Android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button

How can I get a material button in android? I have tried this code but don't know how to include an image like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/material_button"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add to Cart"/>
```

[image]

Comment: There are free icons under `New > Vector Assets` on Android Studio. Set them as `android:drawableLeft` of the `Button` and you'll achieve something like your sample  as well.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For `Material Button` use `icon` and `iconGravity` properties like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Icon Button"
        app:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"/>
```

Docs : [Here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/)

Comment: **Note**: _namespace_ should be an **app** and not the _android_